Find correct object in array based on multiple attributes / conditions
I have a website which interacts with 3rd party API which will handle shipping costs for products. On our website the 'productId' we have match to their 'externalProductId' in their catalog, but they have multiple entries for our ProductID since they classify different productId's in their database based on productId and weight. so in our website one product like 'Bag' has multiple entries on theirs since they have multiple entries for 'Bags' products based on the weight entered. The website is also international so they have weights listed in both lbs and kgs. We need to match our productId with their 'externalProductId' and pick the correct product from their catalog so we can send it to their pricing API. I would need to do this lookup for every product a customer picks from our website to send it to the shipper pricing API so they can see shipping estimates.
One other issue is their minimum weights for all products is always 0 so I could also put logic in the array search where I hard code how to find the product which is between their maximum weights >50lbs but <70lbs but tomorrow if they change the pricing / weight ranges for these it would not work so i would rather find the products in their catalog dynamically for the correct weight which match our productId and 'externalProductId' and finds the correct one out of the multiple matches that is in the weight range. Can someone point out what would be the most efficient way to search the catalog based on these multiple search criteria?
Here is a sample product from our website
  { 'productId' : 'BAG', 'weight': 60, 'unit':'lbs' }


There are two products in their catalog matching the 'externalProductId': 'BAG' but the correct matching product that I would need to find in their product catalog would be because it also matches the weight range.
{
    "productId": "BG2",
    "externalProductId": "BAG",
    "productName": "Bag",
    "weight": {
      "minimum": [
        {
          "minWeight": 0,
          "unit": "lbs"
        },
        {
          "minWeight": 0,
          "unit": "kgs"
        }
      ],
      "maximum": [
        {
          "maxWeight": 70,
          "unit": "lbs"
        },
        {
          "maxWeight": 32,
          "unit": "kgs"
        }
      ]
    }
  },

The 3rd Party product catalog with all the products
[
  {
    "productId": "BG1",
    "externalProductId": "BAG",
    "productName": "Bag",
    "weight": {
      "minimum": [
        {
          "minWeight": 0,
          "unit": "lbs"
        },
        {
          "minWeight": 0,
          "unit": "kgs"
        }
      ],
      "maximum": [
        {
          "maxWeight": 50,
          "unit": "lbs"
        },
        {
          "maxWeight": 23,
          "unit": "kgs"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "productId": "BG2",
    "externalProductId": "BAG",
    "productName": "Bag",
    "weight": {
      "minimum": [
        {
          "minWeight": 0,
          "unit": "lbs"
        },
        {
          "minWeight": 0,
          "unit": "kgs"
        }
      ],
      "maximum": [
        {
          "maxWeight": 70,
          "unit": "lbs"
        },
        {
          "maxWeight": 32,
          "unit": "kgs"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "productId": "GF1",
    "externalProductId": "GLF",
    "productName": "Golf Bag",
    "weight": {
      "minimum": [
        {
          "minWeight": 0,
          "unit": "lbs"
        },
        {
          "minWeight": 0,
          "unit": "kgs"
        }
      ],
      "maximum": [
        {
          "maxWeight": 50,
          "unit": "lbs"
        },
        {
          "maxWeight": 23,
          "unit": "kgs"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "productId": "GF2",
    "externalProductId": "GLF",
    "productName": "Golf Bag",
    "weight": {
      "minimum": [
        {
          "minWeight": 0,
          "unit": "lbs"
        },
        {
          "minWeight": 0,
          "unit": "kgs"
        }
      ],
      "maximum": [
        {
          "maxWeight": 70,
          "unit": "lbs"
        },
        {
          "maxWeight": 32,
          "unit": "kgs"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "productId": "MI1",
    "externalProductId": "MUS",
    "productName": "Music Instrument",
    "weight": {
      "minimum": [
        {
          "minWeight": 0,
          "unit": "lbs"
        },
        {
          "minWeight": 0,
          "unit": "kgs"
        }
      ],
      "maximum": [
        {
          "maxWeight": 50,
          "unit": "lbs"
        },
        {
          "maxWeight": 23,
          "unit": "kgs"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "productId": "MI2",
    "externalProductId": "MUS",
    "productName": "Music Instrument",
    "weight": {
      "minimum": [
        {
          "minWeight": 0,
          "unit": "lbs"
        },
        {
          "minWeight": 0,
          "unit": "kgs"
        }
      ],
      "maximum": [
        {
          "maxWeight": 70,
          "unit": "lbs"
        },
        {
          "maxWeight": 32,
          "unit": "kgs"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]


If there can only ever be one matching product in your 3rd-party array, then you probably want to go about it using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

@Cbroe there would be two matching products based on our productId: 'BAG' and their externalProductId: 'BAG' but then i would need to narrow it down to the correct result based on the weight as well.

For each matching external id, subtract the actual weight from the max weight, and take the lowest difference that’s >= 0

you need to rethink your logic at all since they are using the externalProductId as a category and not as an unique id

indexing by externalProductId and the result of each index being a binary tree should do the trick, then it'd be finding the smallest number greater than your value in parsedObj[someId], or just indexing via externalProductId and each item being an array of them and the logic that @James mentioned

If you need to return matching products based on multiple conditions, you can easily do this with several different array methods. For this example, reduce feels the most fitting for multi-conditional use.
Please see the script below:
const findMatchingProducts = (externalProductId, maxProductWeight, productWeightUnit) => {
  const matchingWeightProducts = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    // filter out any products without a matching externalProductId
    if (curr.externalProductId !== externalProductId) {
      return acc;
    }
    
    const {
      weight: {
        minimum,
        maximum,
      },
    } = curr;
    
    const { minWeight } = minimum.find(min => min.unit === productWeightUnit) || {};
    const { maxWeight } = maximum.find(max => max.unit === productWeightUnit) || {};
    
    // filter out any products that don't fall within the min/max weight range
    const isAboveMinWeight = minWeight <= maxProductWeight;
    const isBelowMaxWeight = maxWeight >= maxProductWeight;
    
    // if the product falls within the min/max weight range, add it to the list of matched products
    if (isAboveMinWeight && isBelowMaxWeight) {
      acc.push(curr);
    }
    
    return acc;
  }, []);
  
  // return the list of matched products
  return matchingWeightProducts;
};

console.log(findMatchingProducts('BAG', 60, 'lbs'));

Result:
[
  {
    "productId": "BG2",
    "externalProductId": "BAG",
    "productName": "Bag",
    "weight": {
      "minimum": [
        {
          "minWeight": 0,
          "unit": "lbs"
        },
        {
          "minWeight": 0,
          "unit": "kgs"
        }
      ],
      "maximum": [
        {
          "maxWeight": 70,
          "unit": "lbs"
        },
        {
          "maxWeight": 32,
          "unit": "kgs"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]

For this example, data is the array of products returned from the third-party catalog. In the findMatchingProducts function, it does the following:

ignores any products without a matching externalProductId
gets the min/max weight for any matching products using the weight unit of measurement provided
checks to make sure the matching product min and max weight are above and below the provided max weight respectively
returns the products that match the condition criteria

If you always need only to return a single product, you may need to add additional properties to filter your result set further, or you can just pick the first result as the "best match". If you need to do exact matches on the min/max weights, you can change the condition to use === when comparing the weights instead of just making sure they are under/over the thresholds.

thanks @nick-w-nick, this is awesome! I was thinking of chaining multiple operators to check for these conditions but you showed how to combine all the logic in one reduce function. I need to use reduce more for things like this, appreciate your help!
